# DNS Resolution Fails for ping and curl, but not dig

Tags: macos, dns

I'm running DNSMasq as a local DNS server, so I can resolve `*.local.pcfdev.io` (as discussed here [Using PCF Dev Offline with Mac OS X](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/work-offline.html)). Everything worked when I first set things up.

A couple of days later, after a few restarts of my MacBook, whilst offline I can no longer resolve things like `api.local.pcfdev.io` using `curl` or `ping`. However, `dig` does the right thing.

```
$ dig api.local.pcfdev.io

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> api.local.pcfdev.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46877
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.local.pcfdev.io.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.local.pcfdev.io.    0       IN      A       192.168.11.11

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Sep  6 10:17:44 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53

$ curl api.local.pcfdev.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.local.pcfdev.io
```

I've tried adding `-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains` as an argument to `/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` and restarted the mDNSResponder with `launchctl`, but to no avail.

---

**UPDATE 1**

There is definitely something listening on the right local IP:

```
$ nslookup api.local.pcfdev.io
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   api.local.pcfdev.io
Address: 192.168.11.11

$ ping api.local.pcfdev.io
ping: cannot resolve api.local.pcfdev.io: Unknown host

$ telnet 192.168.11.11 80
Trying 192.168.11.11...
Connected to 192.168.11.11.
Escape character is '^]'.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

After trying the suggestion below of removing all DNS servers from Network Preferences except `127.0.0.1`, I can't resolve anything. I managed to get some debug logging out of `mDNSResponder`:

```
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: DNSServiceCreateConnection START PID[32612](ping)
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: Error socket 75 created 00000000 00000001
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: DNSServiceQueryRecord(15000, 0, api.local.pcfdev.io., Addr) START PID[32612]()
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: Error socket 75 closed  00000000 00000001 (0)
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: DNSServiceQueryRecord(api.local.pcfdev.io., Addr) ADD    0 api.local.pcfdev.io. Addr
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: Cancel 00000000 00000001
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: DNSServiceQueryRecord(api.local.pcfdev.io., Addr) STOP PID[32612]()
mDNSResponder[91]:  74: DNSServiceCreateConnection STOP PID[32612](ping)
```

I did also observe that as explained in the proposed answer, `nslookup` and `dig` don't cause anything to be logged by `mDNSResponder`, but other tools (`ping`, `curl`) do.

So it seems like for whatever reason either `dnsmasq` isn't working (I can establish a TCP connection to `127.0.0.1:53`) or `mDNSResponder` isn't using it.

---

**UPDATE 3**

`etc/resolve.conf` ceases to exist when my wifi adapter is active, but I'm not connected to a network. Could this be why CLI tools don't use the local `dnsmasq` server?

Comment: Is your network adapter down by chance? If you go to 'Network' in System Preferences, is there a green dot next to the adapter that dnsmasq is configured for use in?

Comment: Well, I'm on a train with no wi-fi, so presumably.

Comment: Specifically, is the wifi adapter turned off? If so, please try again with the wifi adapter turned on (even though it might not actually be connected to the internet). For the setup to work, dnsmasq needs to be a DNS server on the network interface *in use*.

Comment: Thanks for trying to track this down. I'm also struggling with this, don't understand why "curl foo:8989" can't find host but "dig foo" can. Yes, "curl 172.20.0.17:8989" works fine. Like you I have Wi-Fi network DNS set to 127.0.0.1 (a dnsmasq running in a docker container). FWIW in my current situation, the problem is specific to the wifi network I connect to -- works fine on my personal hotspot, problem is on a coffeeshop wifi.

Comment: I haven't reverse engineered the programs in question, but my expectation is they are calling entirely different DNS resolution code bases and that's why you are seeing breakage - some are pointing locally, others not. I'd probably dig into `curl` or `wget` or get them in instruments / profiler / debugger and see what's really happening to cause the could not resolve error.

Answer (score 27):

Had this same issue. I think the local DNS cache had bad data from my previous testing. It was quickly fixed by:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: I've noticed that `ping` and `dig` sometimes return different IP addresses (usually with split horizon DNS) and this command fixes it. What the root cause is, I'm not sure, unfortunately.

Comment: I had to turn wifi off then on for it to work

Comment: Stumbled back to this problem, had to do `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to flush dns in Ventura.

Answer (score 8):

*dig* on the one hand and *curl/ping* on the other hand are retrieving data from different hosts:

*dig* queries a DNS server – in your case your localhost (127.0.0.1) – for a database entry: the IP address related to the FQDN api.local.pcfdev.io. The host itself doesn't have to run or even exist at all.

*curl/ping* try to resolve an IP-address with mDNSResponder or by other means and finally operate on/interact with the remote host. If the host 192.168.11.11 doesn't run or doesn't exist at all, both will fail.

Now, either the DNS entry is wrong (api.local.pcfdev.io has another IP than 192.168.11.11) or the DNS entry is correct but the host 192.168.11.11 is not running.

---

Adding *-AlwaysAppendSearchDomains* as an argument to /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder in */System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist* is not recommended. Instead you should add it to /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist (source: `man mDNSResponder`):

> To cause mDNSResponder to run with these optional arguments when it launches on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and later, set the AlwaysAppendSearchDomains or NoMulticastAdvertisements boolean keys to true in /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist and reboot.

In your case it's not necessary at all to set this key, because it's not the cause of your problem.

---

After digging into VirtualBox, PCF Dev (failing repeatedly with some "wrong credentials" trying to log into the VM) and dnsmasq I recommend to devolve DNS queries to dnsmasq only:

- In System Preferences > Network > Interface > DNS server remove all DNS servers except 127.0.0.1 and apply the changes. You may also configure a second *Location* with a 127.0.0.1 only setup and keep your current DNS server in the other configuration.
- add a file /usr/local/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf with the content

  ```
  #use your preferred DNS servers here. In the example I use some Google name servers
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4
  ```
- add `resolv-file=/usr/local/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf` at line ~46 of /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
- add or move `address=/.local.pcfdev.io/192.168.11.11` at/to line ~80 of /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf
- restart dnsmasq with:

  ```
  sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
  sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
  ```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. There is definitely something listening on `192.168.11.11`; the actual public DNS entry for `*.local.pcfdev.io` always points back to the same local IP, so as soon as I connect to the inforwebs `curl` must be getting an answer from _that_ DNS server and is able to figure out what IP address to use.

Comment: It seems like `curl`, `ping`, and the other binaries I want to hit this thing are using one means of looking up DNS entries (which isn't using the `dnsmasq` server on localhost), and `nslookup` and `dig` are using another means.

I guess I need to learn more about mDNSResponder!

Comment: @EngineerBetter Do you have any other entries in System Preferences > Network > Interface > DNS than 127.0.0.1? - I'm gonna install the whole suite (VBox, PCF Dev etc.) and check this... Any special config?

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this. Question has been updated, still having no luck.

Answer (score 2):

DNS issues like these can be maddening. So, as a note to self... :-)

Killing mDNSResponder and re-establishing the WiFi network didn't work in my case. I had issues with hosts on a specific domain. I finally started to see the light when I discovered the crucial command

```
scutil --dns
```

This reports the actual DNS configuration of the system (used by `ping` and others). Its output alerted me to a rogue resolver:

```
resolver #8
  domain   : the.domain.that.wasnt.working
  nameserver[0] : <unreachable IP #1>
  nameserver[1] : <unreachable IP #2>
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)  # pfft!
```

I removed the resolver's config file and my sanity was restored:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolver/the.domain.that.wasnt.working
```

Special thanks to Gordon for his [enlightening answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/366917/62210) on custom resolvers.

Comment: I had two `xyz` and `io` files that were using `127.0.0.1` as DNS nameserver. It took me a whole month to find the files in `/etc/resolver`. I don't know why they were there, I bought a new macbook and just couldn't open `.io` and `.xyz` domains

Answer (score 1):

It took me much longer for me to solve this than it should have. After restarting mDNSResolver dozens of times as recommended on other threads:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I finally tried something else. I disabled Wi-Fi and deleted all of my preferred networks. Then I reestablished the Wi-Fi connection and everything worked okay:

1. Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Wi-Fi (on the left)
2. 'Turn Wi-Fi Off' then select 'Advanced'
3. Delete the Wi-Fi connection you're having trouble with (or all of
   them if you like). Do this by selecting the Wi-Fi network you want to delete and pressing "-"
4. Click 'Apply' and 'OK'
5. Turn Wi-Fi back on.
6. Select your Wi-Fi network and log in again.

YMMV, but this is what finally worked for me. It probably should have been the first thing I tried.

Comment: An unexpected answer but it i was desperate enough to do it. It worked! Once off/on wifi, remote LAN machines can curl http service from my Mac. For things like these, YMMV.