# .io .xyz and other less popular TLDs cannot be resolved

Tags: network, dns, firewall, domain

I bought a new MacBook Pro 2021 M1, and I can't access URLs ending with `.io`, `.xyz`, and other less popular TLDs.
The issue does not come from the browser. I tried many browsers and the terminal commands `ping` and `curl`.

The error message I'm getting depends on which program I'm using to call the URLs. But basically, this is the message I'm getting: "Could not resolve host".

The URLs are all valid because I can open them from my phone, which is connected to the same WiFi network as my MacBook.

I'm sure the problem concerns the firewall (or DNS?). What can I do to fix this problem?

Edit:
I used the following command:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

It worked for a day and now it stopped working again. I didn't change any DNS or Firewall settings in the meantime.

Comment: Which DNS server is defined in Network settings? Try changing it to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1.

Comment: I already did. I also tried 8.8.4.4. But it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Any network-related software running on the Mac?

Comment: NordLayer VPN. But it's off at the moment. I deleted it now, but nothing changed. The problem was there already before I downloaded it.

Comment: Let’s see what your DNS server is responding with when you query it.   Issue the command `host foobar.xyz` and to see what Google’s DNS replies with use `host foobar.xyz 8.8.8.8`.  This will determine if the DNS server itself is correctly resolving the address.

Comment: The first command is returns: `foobar.xyz has address 34.102.136.180
foobar.xyz mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
foobar.xyz mail is handled by 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.`. The second command returns: `Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

foobar.xyz has address 34.102.136.180
foobar.xyz mail is handled by 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
foobar.xyz mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.`

Comment: Need to know more about the full state of your network stack in addition to your DNS settings. For example: any VPN software running in the background (even if not active); use of Apple's IP address hiding; browser extensions; malware protection.

Comment: Using Terminal, try pining the address directly.  Also run a trace:  `traceroute 34.102.136.180`

Comment: @Gilby what exactly do you need to know? I don't think the issue comes from my network. I'm able to connect to the same domains from different machines. I also tried switching networks and it's still not working. I have NordLayer VPN installed on my MacBook. I don't have any further malware protection installed.

Comment: @Allan what exactly is this IP address? And what should I expect it to return?

Comment: That’s the address of the host you looked up.  You provided it in comments

Comment: Silly me, you're right. Here's the result: `traceroute to 34.102.136.180 (34.102.136.180), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  kabelbox (MY_IP)  6.684 ms  3.323 ms  3.333 ms
 2  * * *
 3  ip5886c96d.static.kabel-deutschland.de (88.134.201.109)  18.467 ms  14.765 ms
    ip5886cb75.static.kabel-deutschland.de (88.134.203.117)  16.077 ms
 4  145.254.3.170 (145.254.3.170)  16.226 ms
    145.254.3.168 (145.254.3.168)  17.556 ms  18.070 ms`
*…the list goes on* `9  180.136.102.34.bc.googleusercontent.com (34.102.136.180)  12.444 ms  15.216 ms  13.509 ms`. It doesn't seem to throw an error

Comment: Reaching the IP is not the issue here, it's DNS. You said it also doesn't work from the terminal, but we can see here that it does. Does `ping foobar.xyz` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I ran `scutil --dns` to find this:

```
resolver #9
  domain   : xyz
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #10
  domain   : io
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)
```

Turns out there were two `xyz` and `io` files in `/etc/resolver`.
I don't know why they were there. My MacBook is new and I imported a backup from my old MacBook. I just checked my old MacBook and the `etc/resolver` folder had only a `test` file.

Special thanks to [@llude](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/62210/llude) for his [enlightening answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458442/336690).